# Dead Code Error in Java

Tags: java, dead-code

I have an array of objects. I want scan it and as long as the object I find is not null, increase a counter by 1. When I find the first null object, I want to jumb out of the for loop since there is no reason to continue looping.

I wrote the following code:

```
// counter variable initialized to zero
int counter = 0;

// scan the array
for(int i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {

    // as long as the object found is not null
    while(!this.array[i].equals(null)) {

        // increase the value of the counter by 1
        counter += 1;

    }

    // when the first null object found, jump out of the loop
    break;

}
```

The i++ in the for loop is marked and the warning is Dead Code. However, I guess this makes sense since when I find the first null object, I stop looping. So nothing to worry about, or ...?

Comment: You are breaking your loop after one iteration. So you will never go to the increment statement.

Comment: your while loop shouldn't be a loop... it should be an if statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're *unconditionally* breaking out of the for loop at the end of the first iteration of the `for` loop. That has nothing to do with "when the first null object is found" - it's just at the end of the body of the loop.

Additionally, your `while` loop is never going to finish unless `array[i]` really is null (in which case it'll throw a `NullPointerException`). I think you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] != null) {
        counter++;
    } else {
        break;
    }    
}
```

Or better, use an iterator:

```
int counter = 0;
for (String item : array) { // Or whatever the type should be
    if (item != null) {
        counter++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oooops! I was thinking to use an if statement instead of a while, this always confuses me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the while iteration to `if` condition as once while condition is true it will not break and go to infinite loop. To match your requirement, use the below code

```
if(this.array[i] != null) {
    // increase the value of the counter by 1
    counter += 1;
}
else {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution for this would be:

```
int counter = 0;
for (Object item : array) {
  if (item == null) {
    break;
  }
  ++counter;
}
```